# A proper way to combine date of datetime column with time of datetime column in SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table has two columns, both of type datetime. I would like to combine only the date part of the 1st datetime column with the time part of the 2nd datetime column.

To best describe my question, suppose my table is created in the following way:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
   ID INT identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
   startDate DATETIME,
   startTime DATETIME,
) 

INSERT INTO mytable(startDate,startTime) VALUES(GETDATE()-10, GETDATE()-1/3);
INSERT INTO mytable(startDate,startTime) VALUES(GETDATE()-20, GETDATE()-RAND());
INSERT INTO mytable(startDate,startTime) VALUES(GETDATE()-68, GETDATE()-RAND());
```

I used the following code to do my query:

```
SELECT *, 
  CAST(REPLACE(startTime, CAST(startTime AS nchar(11)),CAST(startDate AS nchar(11))) AS DATETIME) [method1:fail], 
  CAST((CAST(startDate AS nchar(11)) + ' ' + subString(CAST(startTime AS nchar(20)),13,20)) AS datetime) [method2:fail], 
  CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DATE, startDate)) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), CONVERT(TIME, startTime)) [method3:success]
FROM mytable
```

However, both method 1 and 2 fail and I don't know why. The error is that the combined result would clear the second to 0.

```
ID  startDate               startTime               method1:fail    method2:fail    method3:success
1   2018-01-09 13:56:19.490 2018-01-19 13:56:19.490 2018-01-09 13:56:00.000 2018-01-09 13:56:00.000 2018-01-09 13:56:19.490
2   2017-12-30 13:56:19.490 2018-01-19 11:47:20.133 2017-12-30 11:47:00.000 2017-12-30 11:47:00.000 2017-12-30 11:47:20.133
3   2017-11-12 13:56:19.493 2018-01-19 11:43:41.587 2017-11-12 11:43:00.000 2017-11-12 11:43:00.000 2017-11-12 11:43:41.587
```

Method 3 works in SQL Server 2008 and newer (I am using SQL Server 2014 on my own computer but my server is 2000). But it would fail SQL server 2000 as date and time data types were introduced in SQL server 2008. Could anybody provide a workaround for SQL Server 2000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if a DATETIME is to represent a DATE, it shouldn't have a time component.  It's not possible to have No time component, so it should be set to midnight.

Second, if a DATETIME is to represent a TIME, it shouldn't have a DATE component. That's not possible either, so it should have a date of `0`.  Which will make note sense shortly.

Strip away the time :

```
DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, StartDate), 0)
-- Calculate the number of WHOLE days between day zero and StartDate
-- Add that number of days to day zero
```

Strip away the date :

```
DATEADD(day, -DATEDIFF(day, 0, StartTime), StartTime)
-- Calculate the number of WHOLE days between day zero and StartTime
-- Subtract that number of days from StartTime
```

One you've done these things, you should be able to add them together.

Whatever you do, DO NOT USE STRING MANIPULATION :)

Comment: Really appreciate your answer, and thanks for your performance alert on using string manipulation. Based on your clue, I find the following way to serve my purpose: select DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, startTime, startDate), startTime) time FROM mytable  -- calculate the day difference and add that difference to startTime

Comment: Just one more question: when you specify the day for DATEDIFF calculation, this function would ignore other parts such as year, month, min, sec, right? i.e., hours, mins do not round to day? For example, SELECT DATEDIFF(day, '2018-01-19 00:00', '2018-01-18 23:59:59') would return -1 but in reality, there is only 1 sec difference, not 1 day

Comment: The way I think of it is that you round down the values to the unit your are using, ***then*** calculate the difference.  So `'2018-01-18 23:59:59'` just becomes `'2018-01-18`' for the purposes of the difference calculation in days, or `'2018-01-18 23:00:00'` in hours, etc, etc.  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/18815

Comment: May I ask how datetime variables are added, e.g., how yy, mm, dd, hh, mi, ss get added? For example, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getDate()), 0)  returns the same yy, mm, dd as getDate() (present time), whereas hh, mi, ss are 0. DATEADD(day, -DATEDIFF(day, 0, StartTime), StartTime) returns the same hh, mi, ss as StartTime; but it's returned yyyy = 1900 (not 0), mm = 01 (not 0), dd = 01 (not 0). Why the two dates still add to 2018 (1900 + 2018 ? or 0 + 2018)? What's exactly happening behind? Thanks.

Comment: The date is stored as an integer for the number of days from "Day 0", and an integer number of "ticks" from midnight.  Which date "Day 0" is, and how many microseconds are in a "tick" depends on whether you'r using `DATETIME` or `SMALLDATETIME`, and what version of SQL Server you use.  As for the idea of the year or month or day being 0, that would be nonsense.  There is no Year = `0` *(1 BC is followed by 1AD)*, the same applies to month and day of month.  The `STRING` that you get back ***is not the data being held internally***, it's the result of a `to_string()` function call.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. i just feel curious what is internally represented as "Day 0, Year 0" in SQL? There must be some simple representation to make the addition and subtraction work. For example, SELECT DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, anyDatetime, 0), anyDatetime) is supposed to return "Year 0, day 0, month 0". Why the shown result is "1900-01-01 00:00:00.000". I don't understand the meaning of year 1900 here...

Comment: I already answered that.  ***Nothing*** is supposed to return `0000-00-00` because that's ***not*** a date.  Internally the dates are just two integers, one for the number of elapsed days *(since a date chosen Internally)*, one for the number of elapses ticks *(since midnight)*.  When you ***display*** the date those values are ***THEN*** converted in to strings; the elapsed days become the date, in whatever format you choose, the elapsed ticks become the time, in whatever format you choose.  In your example having 0 elapsed days means `zero days since 1st Jan 1900`.

Comment: Note, the base date that sql server counts up from isn't always `'1900-01-01'`, a `SMALLDATETIME` uses `'1970-01-01'`.  But that ***does not matter***.  It's just "the date you get happen to get when asking to show date 0" *(As from `CAST(0 AS SMALLDATETIME)`)*.  And when you add two `DATETIME` or `SMALLDATETIME` values together, you're adding the number of elapsed days together, and the number of ticks in the same way.  If you need more, please use a good search engine.